# Ant: scan file and write property

Tags: file, ant, properties

In a file called `foo.fxml` in `${basedir}` there is a section that reads

```
<!-- ANT SEARCH HERE 5 -->
```

where 5 may be any integer.

How can I get an ant property to hold the value of that integer, in this case, `5`?

Answer (score 1):

There's two steps to this. First, you need to read the file, which you can do with [LoadFile](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html). Then you can use a regular expression to get the number in the comment. Ant-Contrib has [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) which is good for this.